# drag and drop in scrollview in android

Tags: android, drag, android-scrollview

I have a `LinearLayout` in a `ScrollView`. I have added some views to `LinearLayout` and I want to implement drag up and down on the views which are in the `LinearLayout`. It's like a list of items that you want to order.

I partially did this using `DragShadowBuilder` on `LongClickEvent` and `DragListener`.

Here's the problem:

1) The drag goes out of the parent view. I want to restrict that to within the parent  `LinearLayout`.

2) When I drag a view, the `ScrollView` does not scroll.

Please suggest how I can implement this.

Comment: can you please post some code ?

Comment: searching for same from a month, but till now dint get any solution

Comment: Here is a library which allows you to easily implement the functionality you describe: https://github.com/justasm/DragLinearLayout

Comment: @Pratap did you get any solution? i am trying the same but dnt get any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this trick to make the scrollview scroll down or up dependes on the location of the ShadowBuilder:

```
@Override
public boolean onDrag(View view, DragEvent event) {

    MainWidget dropZoneView = (MainWidget) view;

    int action = event.getAction();
    switch (action) {
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
        //(... other stuff happens here)
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION:

            ScrollView mainScrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.main_scroll);

            int topOfDropZone = dropZoneView.getTop();
            int bottomOfDropZone = dropZoneView.getBottom();

            int scrollY = mainScrollView.getScrollY();
            int scrollViewHeight = mainScrollView.getMeasuredHeight();

            Log.d(LOG_TAG,"location: Scroll Y: "+ scrollY + " Scroll Y+Height: "+(scrollY + scrollViewHeight));
            Log.d(LOG_TAG," top: "+ topOfDropZone +" bottom: "+bottomOfDropZone);

            if (bottomOfDropZone > (scrollY + scrollViewHeight - 100))
                mainScrollView.smoothScrollBy(0, 30);

            if (topOfDropZone < (scrollY + 100))
                mainScrollView.smoothScrollBy(0, -30);

            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I`ve got some problem with understanding dporZoneView logic, so I`ve changed to 

                        int topOfDropZone = (int) (event.getY() - draggedView.getHeight() / 2);
                        int bottomOfDropZone = (int) (event.getY() + draggedView.getHeight() / 2);
where draggwView is View from ShadowBuilder,passed to startDrag as localState